# How embed ipython notebook to wordpress blog as iframe

Tags: wordpress, iframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to embed iframe hyper linking to the ipython notebook (published using nbviewer) in word press blog.

I am using following code to embed the iframe but it is not working.

```
   [iframe src="http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/sharmak/python/blob/master/concepts/Static_Vs_Class_Method.ipynb" width="100%" same_height_as="window" scrolling="yes"]
```

Any helps ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I was not able to find out.

Comment: Too bad. Me neither. The only approach that seems to roughly work is to convert the notebook to html. Then I create a new post (in wordpress.org) and add some <style> to the top of the post, and then paste into the post all the content between the <html></html> tags in the converted notebook. I followed the instructions here: http://prooffreaderplus.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-quickly-turn-ipython-notebook.html  The CSS still needs to be tweaked and it's not a great work-around but it might do the trick.